# Excel convert decimals to Time

Tags: excel, time, vba

I have a date/time field extracted from SQL.
Value is 2016-08-25-00.56.09.861000

I want to just get the time out of this to check if the time is before or after 9am.

I have extracted the time:

```
=RIGHT(A1, LEN(A1)-11)
```

Is there a way to then convert this to time format 00:59:09 that I can then use to compare against 09:00:00?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`=TIME(MID(A1,FIND(".",A1,1)-2,2),MID(A1,FIND(".",A1,1)+1,2),MID(A1,FIND(".",A1,1)+4,2))`

after that convert result to hh:mm:ss by using format cell

Answer (score 0):

Since your data in A1 is a defined format, you can use:

```
=TIMEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,12,8),".",":"))
```

And format the cell containing this formula as a time.